# Algorithm to split a grid of squares into equally sized sections

Tags: algorithms, geometry

I have a grid of squares, let's say 12x12.

[image]

I want to split this grid into equal sections of 8 squares, which is 18 total sections.

[image]

There is no requirement for sections being convex or compact, and the less uniform the better.

### First attempt

I pick a square to start a section. First the corners, then the edges, then the rest, (because it tends to give better and faster results). To generate the section, I iteratively and randomly pick neighboring squares to the section until there are 8 squares in the section. I then use an algorithm (similar to flood fill) to determine how many "holes" there are left in the grid.

[image]

If the number of holes is not one (if the section created a space that is not able to be filled by a section), the section is recreated, and repeat until the number of holes is one. This repeats for every section created. As you can imagine, this gets pretty slow when the grid size and section size is increased. Is there a faster and more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Yes, might i suggest finding a copy of *Computational Geometry - Algorithms and Applications, 3rd Ed* or equivalent. It discusses many of these basic algorithms and how to adapt them to different situations.

Comment: @Kain0_0: I had a short look into the table of contents of that book which gives me the impression it will not help to solve this particular task. This kind of problem is a discrete combinatorial one, computational geometry deals mostly with problems in R^2 or R^3 space.

Comment: Working from the border to the center, the border randomly electing 1-8 squares per section is easy and the backtracking not overly inefficient. And the forms will be very random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement *"the less uniform the better"* is pretty vague, so there can be several different algorithms or heuristics to solve this task, all with different pros and cons. Hence I recommend you define some kind of metrics for non-uniformity first, to make the task less arbitrary.

Said that, the most simple algorithm which comes into my mind is the following:

1. Start with some trivial **valid** tiling. In the given example, using 2x4 tiles would work. Another idea (thanks to @KrisVanBael) is to combine squares by going from one row from left to right, then the next row from right to left, just like in the old arcade game [centipede](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGEZ3NNH6cs). This should be straightforward and O(N), where N = total number of squares. Here is such an example for tiles of size 5:

[image]

2. Apply modifications on this tiling of the following form: Randomly pick two neighbored tiles with at least two touching squares. Add one of those squares from tile 1 to tile 2 and the other one from tile 2 to tile 1. Or more general, take the space occupied by two neighbored tiles and fill it with two new tiles of the same size, but using different squares than before. Make sure this results in a configuration where the squares of each tile are still connected to each other (otherwise undo the modification).

For the above example, this could look like this:

[image]

Note modifications of this type can be implemented in an O(1) manner.

Now repeat step 2 until your metrics for non-uniformity reaches a certain threshold, or until your program reaches a certain time limit. Note each modification will keep the tiling always valid, so you can stop the algorithm whenever you want, always with a solution to return.

Comment: My comment "the less uniform the better" was pretty unimportant. I was talking more about an algorithm to be able to split the grid up for whatever size and section size I have. A 6x10 grid with sections of 5 cannot be tiled using squares.

Comment: Nice idea, Doc. Step 2 could be extended with other types of atomic modifications that preserve the rules. 
step 1 can be generalized by constructing a snake that fills the square (many algo’s possible, aome

Comment: @Evan: a 6x10 grid can be tiled with 1x5 tiles trivially. If you mean something different, try to give a different explanation, please.

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, but I'm fairly certain that your step 2 doesn't work for sections 1 wide.

Comment: @DocBrown Also I really like your step 2, but am confused on step 1 for different grid sizes and tile sizes. How could I find to use 1x5 tiles computationally, and how could I place them? (e.g. some have to be rotated)

Comment: @Evan: I added some examples to make this more clear. And in a 6 x 10 grid, one could trivially take each row (which is a 1x 10 rectangle) and fill it with two 1x5 tiles.

Comment: Hehe, I spent several hours today, looking for a more interesting (fractal) snake scheme for step 1 that works on any size rectangle.